# Using views on tables with same schema

Tags: sql, oracle

We are using multiple tables to persist data of an entity month-wise. Meaning, we have table names as xx01, xx02...xx12. The table definition for all these table is same except the name. We are doing like this so that we can drop a table when we think it is old. Ex: drop Feb table in Dec. The table drop will be essentially free. 
My question is, can I create a view which can read from any of these tables? 
The view should be able to fetch data from any of these tables, potentially from more than one table for range queries. 
DB: Oracle 12c.
PS: We can't have a column for month and partition on it because we have to partition and subpartition basing on other columns for read performance.

Comment: Get rid of all these tables and views and create a partitioned table, which is made to solve this exact problem. Once you get past the initial learning curve it's much simpler to create, maintain, and use. [Basic info here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-9F7809B6-E68A-4425-AC99-BE00C7805408.htm#VLDBG00406)

Comment: What are the columns for partitions? With VIRTUAL columns you can define partitions even on more than just one column.

Comment: In order to keep read performance you may consider Bitmap-Indexes for such columns. What is your typical query?

Comment: You can partition and subpartition on multiple columns, in case that helps. But if partitioning is really not an option, yes you can create a view over all of the tables. Make sure you expose a pseudo-partition key (e.g. the business date or month etc) in the view definition, and use it when querying the view. You'll need to rebuild the view each time the list of tables changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a better way, and it would work on Oracle: you should just have a single table xx, with a column for month (or month/year) - but  make it a partitioned table on that month (or month/year) column.

What Oracle will do is create a separate storage area for each value of the partition column, and it will be smart enough to only look at the appropriate storage area(s), if your queries include a value (or range) for that partition column.

If you ever decided you did not want to keep a particular month (or month/year) any more, you can tell Oracle to drop that one partition, while keeping the rest of the table as is.

Comment: I edited the question. We already do partition and subpartition on other two columns. So cannot do it on months.